# Find the value of $k$ (integral)

Tags: calculus, integration

If $k$ is a positive number such that 
$$\int _0^k |\sin x |\,dx = \frac{17}{2},$$
find the value of $k$.

hints/tips welcomed

Comment: Recall the picture of $y=\sin x$. It is now easy to visualize $y=|\sin x|$. The integral to $\pi$ is $2$. So the integral to $2\pi$ is $4$. So to $4\pi$ it is $8$. So to $4\pi$ want to add $w$ where $\int_0^w \sin x\,dx=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $k$ is $\displaystyle k = \frac{13\pi}{3}$.

Observe that $$\begin{align}\int_0^k|\sin(x)|dx & = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\, dx - \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sin(x)\, dx + \int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}\sin(x)\, dx - \int_{3\pi}^{4\pi}\sin(x)\, dx + \int_{4\pi}^k \sin(x)dx\\ & = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + \int_{4\pi}^k \sin(x)dx\\ & = 8 + \int_{4\pi}^k \sin(x)dx\\ &= 8 - \cos(k) + \cos(0)\\ & =9 - \cos(k)\\& = \frac{17}2 \\ & = 8.5\end{align}$$

Solve the equation
$$9 - \cos(k) = 8.5$$ $$\cos(k) = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$k = \frac{\pi}{3}(6n-1)$$ and $$k = \frac{\pi}{3}(6n+1).$$ Choose smallest $n$ such that $k > 4\pi$. So, $n = 2$. Thus, $k = \frac{13\pi}{3}$.

Comment: that doesn't help

Comment: @MissT You know what *would* help...actually showing some of your own work instead of expecting other people to do it for you.

Comment: @MagicMan There might be a more polite way of communicating here.

Comment: @Dr.MV I think it's pretty insulting to post a garbage question and then to belittle an answer that maps out a way to think.

Comment: @MagicMan Your answer is fine and I understand that one might be frustrated with the situation.  But the tone might be interpreted negatively.  Chin up.  There are much worse things about which to become upset.

Comment: @Dr.MV I didn't answer the question.

Comment: @MagicMan this answer only had the final solution before he added the rest. calm your self

Comment: @MagicMan I saw that after I posted the comment.  But, the main theme still retains.  Don't let insignificant events bring you down.

Comment: @MissT I know that. I'm saying you shouldn't belittle an answer when your own question is poorly posed and poorly formatted. No work or anything. Which is why it is on its way to being put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the hint above by Andre. I work with that.

So by knowing $\int_0^{4\pi} |\sin x| dx = 8$. So to visualize, we have

$$ \overbrace{\int_0^{4\pi} |\sin x| dx}^{=8} + \overbrace{\int_0^k |\sin x| dx}^{\text{want k so that integral}=0.5} = 8.5$$

So we've reduced the problem down to $$\int_0^k |\sin x| = 1/2$$ Here, we now make sure of the fact that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} |\sin x| = 1$ So we are looking for a $k$ such that $o \leq k \leq 1$. Knowing that $sin(x) > 0$ between 0 and 1, we can remove the absolute bars so we have $$\int_0^k sin(x) dx = 1/2$. You can probably take it from here.

$k$ for the reduced integral equals $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and adding that to $4 \pi$ equals $13pi \ 3$